# JPEG compression in Python turns negative

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, jpeg

I'm trying to JPEG compress a greyscale image in Python with Numpy. I've tried two different quantisation methods: applying a mask and dividing by predefined weights, but in both cases the values of the compressed image are way too high.
[image: This is how it looks with a mask quantisation. Looks similar with weights.]

A printout in the python  IDE of the original image and the processed image gives the following:

```
Uncompressed:
[[23 25 26 ..., 17 18 19]
 [23 25 26 ..., 16 17 18]
 [24 25 27 ..., 15 16 16]
 ..., 
 [68 52 45 ..., 20 18 17]
 [66 27 14 ..., 18 17 15]
 [68 29 14 ..., 17 15 14]]

Compressed:
[[ 278.70719913  280.56095939  281.89426619 ...,  273.41847541
   274.41642174  275.11264205]
 [ 279.49137088  281.20996776  282.42671682 ...,  272.37174176
   273.05506856  273.59872544]
 [ 280.26810477  281.7369523   282.73833074 ...,  271.18033959
   271.45606872  271.81185441]
 ..., 
 [ 346.60801656  332.97428913  311.95287258 ...,  275.36547554
   273.90408787  273.14715488]
 [ 326.40626296  308.74082394  285.71491905 ...,  274.10082953
   272.12056066  271.00663571]
 [ 303.05777135  281.42687625  254.22921445 ...,  273.12188339
   270.79982443  269.46372928]]
```

Obviously this results in areas of the image that should be dark becoming bright and vice versa. I suspect the error lies in the calculation of the DCT transform matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def dct_basis():
    """ Calculates matrix with dtc basis vectors. """
    rows = np.arange(1,16,2)
    cols = np.arange(8)
    rows.shape = (1,8)
    cols.shape = (8,1)
    coeffs = np.dot(cols,rows) # param in cos() in dct matrix, without pi/16
    coeffs = coeffs.T
    radians = (np.pi/16) * coeffs  # now make the numbers radians
    dct = np.cos(radians)
    dct = np.sqrt(2./8)*dct
    col0 = np.ones(8)*(1/np.sqrt(8)) 
    col0.shape = (8,1)
    dct[:,0:1] = col0  # first column filled by sqrt(2/width)
    dct = np.matrix(dct)
    return dct

def get_weights(): # commmented out is for quantising w/ weights
##    with open('weights.txt','r') as f:
##        W = f.read()
##    W = weights.split()
##    W = map(float,weights)
##    W = np.asarray(weights)
##    W = np.reshape(weights, (8,8))
##    W = np.matrix(weights)
    a = np.triu([1,1,1,1,1]) # this is for quantising w/ mask
    W = np.zeros((8,8))
    W[:5,3:] = a
    W = np.fliplr(W)
    return W    

def jpeg_encode():
    I = np.matrix(mpimg.imread('uggla2.tif'))
    print "Pre: ",I
    # More effective coding if values are centered around zero.
    # This assumes a resolution of 256 colours.
    I = I - 128
    T = dct_basis()
    W = get_weights()
    blocksize = 8
    size = I.shape
    bx = size[0]/8
    by = size[1]/8
    C = np.matrix(np.zeros(size))
    for x in range(bx):
        for y in range(by):
            tmp = T.T * I[x*blocksize : x*blocksize + blocksize,
                          y*blocksize : y*blocksize + blocksize] * T
            C[x*blocksize : x*blocksize + blocksize,
              y*blocksize : y*blocksize + blocksize] = \
                                          np.around(np.multiply(tmp,W))
    return C

def jpeg_decode():
    C = jpeg_encode()
    T = dct_basis()
    W = get_weights()
    blocksize = 8
    size = C.shape
    bx = size[0]/8
    by = size[1]/8
    I = np.matrix(np.zeros(size))
    for x in range(bx):
        for y in range(by):
            tmp = C[x*blocksize : x*blocksize + blocksize,
                    y*blocksize : y*blocksize + blocksize]
            #tmp = np.multiply(tmp,W)
            I[x*blocksize : x*blocksize + blocksize,
              y*blocksize : y*blocksize + blocksize] = \
                                             T * tmp * T.T
    I = I + 128
    print "Post: ",I
    return I

# Running the module from terminal
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure()
    a=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    img1 = mpimg.imread('uggla2.tif')
    imgplot =  plt.imshow(img1, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
    a.set_title('Uncompressed')
    img2 = jpeg_decode()
    a=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
    imgplot =  plt.imshow(img2, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
    a.set_title('Compressed')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I am deeply suspicious of `I = I - 128`. What is the dtype of `I`? `plt.imread` usually returns a uint16 array, which looks consistent with the printout you have shown in your question. Since this is an unsigned type, any values less than 128 would underflow. Try casting it to a float type first, e.g. `I = np.matrix(mpimg.imread('uggla2.tif'), dtype=np.float64)`.

Comment: As an aside, I would [strongly encourage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use) you to use `np.ndarray` rather than `np.matrix`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Ali M. The uint16 data type was the error all along! This is how it looks using mask and weights respectively for quantisation:
[image]